Не могу понять что не так с сохранением моих файлов
Всем добрый день.
Изучаю Питон самостоятельно, по стандарту он у меня установился по пути .../programs/Python/Python313 и все файлы в IDE среде там же сохраняются, в папке Lib
Вопрос вот в чем: как в Питоне менять каталог, и сохранять файлы другим путем, чтобы не засорять Lib?
Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но я уже устал перебирать каталог в поисках моих файлов среди остальных...

Тут бы хорошо указать какая у вас собственно IDE. Сама то IDE по идее должна другой какой-то каталог назначить домашним для ваших файлов/проектов, не каталог питона. Может вы его сами выбрали?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Использую стандартную IDE которая с Питоном идет @CrazyElf

@aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за ссылку, в следующий раз постараюсь быть более грамотным)


стандартную IDE которая с Питоном идет ...
Ого. Не думал, что такая есть.


Можно указать в свойствах ярлыка для IDLE рабочий каталог - тот, который Вам нужен. Будет предлагать открывать файлы скриптов и предлагать сохранять файлы скриптов в этот каталог.
